# Trigger not working on Bulk records properly

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, bestpractice, bulkification

**Requirement** - Requirement is to generate a random number(not sequential) for every case getting created, provided number remains unique in salesforce database. The number is then appended with Year and Month, yields actual operating number.
  *(Reason I cannot use auto number is, it is sure that one day in future the 4 digit autonumber will exhaust and become 5 digit and the format, then our standard format year+month+date+4digitRandomNumber will fail).* 
**Example**- 20191012xxxx(YYYY+MM+DD+4digitRandomNumber).
 Below is the trigger, which is working fine for few set of records but getting duplicate values in random numbers for Bulk records:

```
   trigger randomOperatingNumber on Case (before insert) {    
    List<Case> casesFromDBToday = [Select Case_Number_from_trigger__c from Case where createddate = today];
    Set<String> caseNums = new Set<String>();
    for(Case caselist : casesFromDBToday){
        caseNums.add(caselist.Case_Number_from_trigger__c);
    }
    
    Integer randomNumber;
    for( Case c: Trigger.New){
        Boolean isInserted = false;
        while(!isInserted){
            //Generate any number between 1 to 7999
            String randomNumber = String.valueOf(Math.round(1+Math.random()*7998));
            //Make it an exact 4 digit number
            if(randomNumber.length()==3)
                randomNumber = '0' + randomNumber;
            else if(randomNumber.length()==2)
                randomNumber = '00' + randomNumber;
            else If(randomNumber.length()==1)
                randomNumber = '000' + randomNumber;
            //Check if this number already exists in Database. Insert or recreate number accordingly.
            If(!caseNums.contains(randomNumber)){
                system.debug('Inside IF');
                caseNums.add(randomNumber);
                c.Case_Number_from_trigger__c = randomNumber;
                isInserted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code runs fine for single test records, but getting duplicated when Bulk records are inserted.
[image]
Any idea/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Your client wants a sequentially generated case number, that is available out of the box. Create a formula field that concatenates case number with year and date based on case created date (that'll never change in a given org) and voila! You've met the requirement.

Comment: I would highly suggest editing the standard Case Number field and changing the Display Format to `{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{0000}`. This sequential suffix will initially be padded with zeroes to 4 characters and does not represent the "Case Number per day" concept where the numbering would begin again from 1 each day but I may be reading too far into your requirement past what was explicitly written.

Answer (score 3):

It should be immediately obvious why you would have duplicates.

You have 6000+ records
You only have ~5000 values to assign

Naturally, that dataset is guaranteed to have at least ~1000 duplicates (pidgeonhole principle).

**+edit: question was updated to use a slightly bigger number (8000), but the crux of the issue remains.**

There's also the birthday paradox to consider. With only 5000 possible values, you have a 50/50 chance of repeating a value after you generate a mere 83 values.

If you want non-sequential, unique numbers using `math.random()`, there's no way around you needing to drastically increase the size of your random number. Even then, using a random number generator means that you will *always* have a chance to see a repeat number.

You need to make a choice about how important uniqueness is to you, and study your data.

Options I can see here are:

- You could create your own auto-number utility (be aware of simultaneous requests) that would reset itself each day
- You can expand your "operating number" so that it includes the time down to the second (the finer the granularity, the less your chance of having 2 exact duplicates)
- Just use the record id (it's already unique). Trim out the "5002v000..." bit if that helps

Comment: Oh my Bad, I pasted previous version of code and latest screenshot.. Let me edit the code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Well I considered using auto number in the 1st place but I should not as per requirements..

Comment: @KKumar Raising the total numbers you can use to 8000 only gets you to 106 records before you have a 50/50 chance of a repeat. To give you an idea of how big your number would need to be, to go 100,000 iterations and only just pass a 50/50 chance of a duplicate, you range of possible numbers would need to be from 1 to 7.3 billion (which is a problem for 32-bit signed integers, you'd need 34 bits to represent that number). Clients can "require" all they want, but no amount of requiring will make impossible things possible. You should push back and ask why this is a requirement.

Comment: Basically as per what Derek F said, this requirement is difficult to realize because of the fact that there are many different ways a record could be created, and how this could happen in parallel. One option would be to allow the records to be inserted with no value for this field and have a "single threaded" process (a batch or queueable written to only allow a single concurrent execution) look for records that need the value to be set and then sets it in an entirely controlled manner (here no need for random, just an in-day sequence).

Comment: Agreed. Thanks Derek, Phil